# Swipe views in one ViewController

Tags: swift, swipe, viewcontroller

I want to make something like loop of days in my ViewController

So, I got this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz5wu.png)

And i want to swipe views between an array of days. For example swipe right to get tuesday in the same ViewController.

---

- How to do this in one ViewController, or better should i do 7 VC for that.
- Show me some helpful examples/tut of similar issues.

Could you please advice, how to deal with it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to build this view as an entire screen, or just a part of the screen. However, like ocanal said, it is quite easy using a UIPageViewController.

What you do, you draw out a UIPageViewController in your storyboard and create a custom class from a UIPageViewController as a swift file. Don't forget to conform to the UIPageViewControllerDataSource and UIPageViewControllerDelegate. Like this:

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       dataSource = self
       delegate = self
   }

}
```

Next drop a UIViewController in the storyboard and create your custom UIViewController as a Swift file. Also give the UIViewController an ID in the storyboard, like "myViewController". The minimum content your custom view controller needs are the outlets that need to be displayed and the variables that set these outlets. You can't directly set the outlets, so you need to create the variables that set the outlets.

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myOutlet: UILabel

var myVariable = ""
var index

override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myOutlet.text = myVariable
```

}

Go back to your custom UIPageViewController and in viewWillAppear instantiate the first view you want to show with the following calls.

```
override function viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let index = 0
    let startingViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! MyViewController 
    startingViewController.index = index
    startingViewController.myVariable = contentArray[index]
//The contentArray contains the content you want to display in your view controller.
    self.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then implement the datasource methods func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? and func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?. The latter can, for instance, be implemented like this:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let index = (viewController as! MyViewController).index
    index += 1

    if (index < 0) || (index>= contentArray.count) {return nil}

    let contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! MyViewController 
    contentViewController.myVariable = contentArray[index]
    contentViewController.index = index
    return contentViewController
}
```

of course, you should officially not force unwrap your optionals, but I leave the proper coding to you. This will give you a great swiping experience where you swipe the days of the week as pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to learn how it works,
You can search for [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipagecontrol), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ) method works for multiple UIViewController

And what I suggest you is creating a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) with paging scroll in just one UIViewController.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxIAT7f-yh8) is an example to follow,

Or if you just want to do, you can use [PageMenu](https://github.com/orazz/PageMenu).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lakshikabhardwaj/LBViewControllerCollection

a sample code

```
let mainViewController = CPPageMenuVC(nibName: "CPPageMenuVC", bundle: nil) let pageMenuarray :[PageModal] = [PageModal(pageTitle: "Cat", pageVC: catVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "Cow", pageVC: cowCv),PageModal(pageTitle: "Chat", pageVC: cpCatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "ElephantElephant", pageVC: elephantVC)]
```